# Integral $\int_{-2}^0 \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate $$\int_{-2}^0 \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}dx$$ So far I had no succes using trig substitution or integration by parts, also some random substitution like $x=2t$ and moved the exponential to the numerator, but I am stuck. Could you perhaps give me an idea? (this is a college admission problem)

Comment: It is interesting to note that the antiderivative of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}$ is given by $$\begin{align}\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}\,dx&=-2\log\left(e^{-x/2}\left((x+2)+\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}\right) \right)+C\\\\&=x-2\log\left((x+2)+\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}\right)+C\end{align}$$whereas Wolfram Alpha reports [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%2F(sqrt((x%2B2)%5E2%2Be%5Ex))) that no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Comment: well,  humans designed the algorithm so it cant be flawless. How did you find that?

Comment: Just follow the approach used by @interstellarProbe.

Comment: that $2$ does anything? If we replace by $a$ can we find an anti-derivate?

Comment: Try it with a different number.

Comment: If you replace the 2 with an a, then the substitution becomes:

$$(x+a)e^{-x/2} = \tan \theta$$

$$\left(\dfrac{2-x-a}{2}\right)e^{-x/2}dx = \sec^2 \theta d\theta$$

So, you would need the numerator to be $k(2-x-a)$ where $k$ is a nonzero real number. In the case where $a=2$, we had $k=-1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Factor out $e^x$ in the denominator. Once you take the square root, you get $e^{x/2}$ in the denominator. Then, make the substitution:

Let $(x+2)e^{-x/2} = \tan \theta$

$-\dfrac{x}{2}e^{-x/2}dx = \sec^2 \theta d\theta$

At $x=-2$, $\tan \theta = 0$

At $x=0$, $\tan \theta = 2$

So, your integral becomes:

$$\int_{-2}^0 \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}dx = -2\int_0^{\arctan 2} \sec \theta d\theta = -2\ln(\sqrt{5}+2)$$

Comment: Clear and concise (+1).  Well done.

Comment: Thank you sir. Could you please explain how did you tought of that?

Comment: Typically, when I see a sum of squares in the denominator, I look to get it into the form $1+u^2$ for some $u$, as I know I can make the substitution $u=\tan \theta$ and simplify the expression to $1+\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta$, getting rid of the troublesome addition in the denominator. The rest just happened to work out.

Comment: I think you lost $2e^{-x/2}$

Comment: @Vasya where? it looks correct to me

Comment: (+1) for the answer and also for the tip , seems like quite a useful one.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the antiderivative of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}$ is given by $$\begin{align}\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}\,dx&=-2\log\left(e^{-x/2}\left((x+2)+\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}\right) \right)+C\\\\&=x-2\log\left((x+2)+\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}\right)+C\end{align}$$whereas Wolfram Alpha reports [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%2F(sqrt((x%2B2)%5E2%2Be%5Ex))) that no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Answer (score 7):

Mathematica could not solve this as written,
$$
I=\int_{-2}^0 \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}dx
$$
I introduced a parameter $a$
$$
I(a)=\int_{-2}^0 \frac{x}{\sqrt{a e^x+(x+2)^2}}dx
$$
took a [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) with respect to $a$
$$
\mathcal{M}_a[I(a)](s)= \Gamma(s)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-s\right)\int_{-2}^0 \frac{x \left(\frac{e^x}{(2+x)^2}\right)^{-s}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{(x+2)^2}}dx
$$
Mathematica can solve this
$$
\mathcal{M}_a[I(a)](s)= \frac{-4^s\Gamma(s)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-s\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}s}
$$
and the inverse Mellin transform gives \begin{equation}
I(a) = -2 \text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}\right)
\end{equation}
which for $a=1$ checks out numerically as around $I \approx -2.88727$

Comment: Well done!  (+1)

Comment: What is Mellin transform?

Comment: @Sonkun see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform)

Comment: (+1) for the answer but Seeing as how this is for  a college exam and OP is not familiar with integral transforms , this would be of little help to him.

Comment: Good job, on an integral calculator website, it couldn't come up with an anti-derivative but it approximated the definite integral to -2.88727095035762.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the antiderivative of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}$ is given by $$\begin{align}\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}\,dx&=-2\log\left(e^{-x/2}\left((x+2)+\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}\right) \right)+C\\\\&=x-2\log\left((x+2)+\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}\right)+C\end{align}$$whereas Wolfram Alpha reports [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%2F(sqrt((x%2B2)%5E2%2Be%5Ex))) that no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Comment: @MarkViola I remember comments on other questions mentioning difficulties with CAS integration of mixed transcendental algebraic functions.

Comment: @TheIntegrator You are right, this is a very experimental technique. At the very best it will introduce the names of a few concepts.

Comment: @Sonkun Sorry if this was a confusing approach, I will try to add a few steps in to make things clearer and perhaps more useful. There are three main integral transforms in order of decreasing importance: Fourier, Laplace and Mellin (although there are many others as well). Mellin transforms can in some situations be thought of as a bridge between a function and the coefficients of its series expansion (by the Ramanujan Master Theorem). I use them to take awkward looking parts of the integrand out at the expense of having to compute the inverse transform later.